# 2-connected graph problem (West, Introduction to Graph Theory, ex. 4.2.15)

Tags: graph-theory

I am struggling with this problem for hours but it seems to be easy. Here is the problem:

Proof that every vertex $v$ in 2-connected graph $G$ has neighbour $u$ such that $G - v - u$ is connected.

Any help is highly appreciated! I think that I might be missing a trivial solution here =(

EDIT:
So far, I tried to create an incremental process that will yield an appropriate neighbour for selected vertex $v$. So, one can remove $v$ and any $v$'s neighbour $u$ from $G$. The resulting graph can be connected or not. If it is connected, then we have found our neighbour and can stop the process. Otherwise, Graph $G$ is spliced into several components. It is clear that in each component should be at least one neighbour of $v$ as $G$ is 2-connected. I think that on this step I should choose one of these neighbours and remove it instead of initial $u$. But I cannot find the proof that it will not lead to another cut of the graph.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @user37238 I added some of my thoughts, hope this helps.

Comment: In an ear decomposition, consider the last ear that actually added a vertex. That vertex and any neighbor on that ear are what you need.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk Thank you for a great advice! But I am not sure that it is a solution yet. For example, consider graph $G = C_{10} + e$, where edge $e = \{u, v\}, v = 1, u = 3$. This graph can be decomposed into a cycle $C_{10}$ and a single ear that consists of only one edge $e$. If we remove $v$ and its neighbour $u$ then $G$ will be cut into two components $K_1$ and $L_7$.

Comment: I came back here, because I realized that I had answered a simpler problem, but you make clear that the answer was also wrong. Thanks for that. Ear decomposition does not seem to be the proper approach here. Another approach works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be our 2-connected graph, $v$ an arbitrary vertex of $G$.
If $G-v$ is still 2-connected, we can take any neighbor of $v$.

Otherwise the block tree of $G-v$ has a leaf block $B$.
Let $w$ be the (unique) cut vertex of $G-v$ in $B$.
$v$ must have a neighbor $u$ in $B-w$, or otherwise $G-w$ would be disconnected(!)

Since $B$ is 2-connected, $B-u$ is connected, so $G-v-u$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you! My problem was that I was considering an abstract block in $G-v$ that can possibly have several cut vertecies. And thus, when it comes to choose $u$, I was falling deep in recursion... A leaf block solves it like a charm!